# Run go command as a gradle task

Tags: go, gradle, terraform, terratest

I am using gradle as the build tool for a terraform project. I do have unit tests written in go for the project under the ..test/... folder . The way I am running test locally is just on the commandline `go test ..test/..`' which will run all `tests` under the test folder. I want to integrate this in the build , so that every build will run this command `'go test ..test/..'`, How do I achieve this in gradle. Can a custom task be utilized to run a `go` command?

I am trying to do something like the following

```
task testExec(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "${buildDir}/test"
    commandLine 'go','test'
} doLast {
    println "Test Executed!"
}
```

But I get the error

```
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'go''
```

For what its worth , I tried other commands and get the same erorr for ex

```
task testExec(type: Exec) {
     workingDir "${buildDir}/test"
     commandLine 'echo','${}buildDir'
} doLast {
     println "Test Executed!"
}
```

gives similar error

```
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'echo''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [gradle plugin](https://github.com/gogradle/gogradle). First you can follow the [starting guide](https://gogradle.github.io/gogradle/docs/getting-started.html#start) and add the plugin:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.blindpirate.gogradle' version '0.11.4'
}

golang {
    packagePath = 'github.com/your/package' // go import path of project to be built, NOT local file system path!
}
```

Then you can run the [following command](https://gogradle.github.io/gogradle/docs/getting-started.html#test-a-project) to execute all go files that follow the file name convention `<name>_test.go`:

```sh
gradlew goTest
```

Otherwise you can also create a [complete custom task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html) or a [custom task with the plugin](https://gogradle.github.io/gogradle/docs/getting-started.html#custom-task).

**EDIT**:

I found the cause of your error. The variable `buildDir` refers to the `build` folder in your project: `<project_folder>/build`. The problem now is that the folder `test` does not exists and the exception is thrown. Instead, you can use the variable `projectDir`.